# Laravel Nothing to Migrate (Migration to PostgreSQL)

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I tried to do database migration to postgreSQL but when i run php artisan migrate it giving "nothing to migrate" response, what should i do

here's my code for migration :

```
<?php

Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     *Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email',50)->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function down()
     {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
     }
}
```

Comment: are you migrating for the first time or you have changed table?

Comment: i'm migrating for the first time

Comment: @NelVanBalthazar Have you changed your env file to point to the postgres server, have you checked the database.php file in app/config/

Comment: @MikeRodham i changed it but problem still happened

Answer (score 1):

Try rollback and see what happens

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Comment: Thanks Man, i try to rollback and try to do "php artisan migrate" again,  succesfully migrated , BUT i checked the table in database, the table doesn't exist. need help...

Comment: does your data base has a migrations table? it should be migrated by default when you migrate for the first time in laravel

Comment: no table at all. empty database. I check mysql database it was effected after rollback and migrate again, i get confused, i have pointed to postgreSQL by configure the .env, but why mysql database  affected.

Comment: i'm using xampp and has cofigured the php.ini for postgreSQL also